# PHP preg_match website content generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

I'm trying to grab information from website. The information is generated by JavaScript and with php preg_match and with Linux command line curl -s command I'm not able to get it.

But, when I open the website's source code on Firefox, I'm able to see the JavaScript generated HTML that I'm trying to grab.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The only way you are able to grab content is if it is static, to get generated code, you are going to need to generate the screen that displays it, this could be resolved by using a hidden iframe in your DOM, dirty, messy and slow, but could work

Comment: Can you give me any tips or direction how to create that screen? This is a minor project so it doesn't really matter if it's a bit dirty, messy or slow...

Comment: Short answer, no, we cannot guide on how to do things, we can't provide guides or tutorials, we can help fix what is broken by providing a minimal, verifiable example of what you have tried